# IDE Fatal Errors: Duplicated key .toast for language JAVA

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, suddenly an error happened just like in the following picture.

> IDE Fatal Errors: Duplicated key .toast for language JAVA

[image: screenshot]

After that the IDE just won't generate any code insight and I need to type all my code manually. Does anyone know how to solve it or has anyone met the same problem?

Comment: Just do a reinstall. It's been the go-to fix for everything since years ago.

Comment: For the next time copy your error Log like a code, not like a `screenshot`, it's easier read code. =)

Comment: Thank you for help and I`m sorry for my poor (Chinese)English.T T

Comment: Sorry to tell you, I have reinstall my android studio and my java jdk, nothing changed. It still reminds me "Duplicated key .toast for language JAVA"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have installed Android Tools? Try to disable it. It seems have some problem with Android Studio 2.0